# How To Display Date Picker on The Page W/O tapping one more button?

Tags: flutter, datepicker

So far, all the examples are showing date picker as a popup after tapping on a tab.

Is there a way to display the date picker as shown below? Thanks!

[Date picker on the page without clicking a tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2UW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always treat pickers as widgets that's why there is no need to call them through the button clicks. Check the full example below or run online [here](https://dartpad.dev/a753a3c781b1763360731bb6e71ff4bb?null_safety=false).

Example Code showing Cupertino date picker:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: CupertinoDatePicker(
        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
        initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime value) {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For material widget:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: CalendarDatePicker(
        onDateChanged: (DateTime value) {},
        lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 30)),
        firstDate: DateTime.now(),
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any further queries regarding it.

Comment: Thanks D C, that makes sense. However, can non-iOS also display Cupertino's Date picker? Or must there be another widget present so that non-iOS gadgets can display material's date picker?

Comment: Yes, the use of Cupertino widgets would work perfectly fine on android devices. Also if you use Cupertino widgets then they would display Cupertino widgets on all devices which means they won't automatically switch to the material.

Comment: You have to use conditions to switch from material to Cupertino on the basis of devices. You had to know which platform the device is running on and on that basis, you had to display a specific widget. But to simplify that job you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets.  Let me know if you have further queries about date pickers.

Comment: thanks, will check it out and get back to you if I have an queries DC :D

Comment: @D C , by any chance you know how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629779/reflect-list-data-back-into-ui-flutter