# Reflect List Data Back Into UI [Flutter]

Tags: database, list, flutter, backend

In short, users can choose their interests during onboarding, UI changes and the interests are added to a list.

When user navigates to another page ie settings, how can the chosen interests be selected alrdy (bool isChosen = true)?... and then users can update their interests from there again?

any guidance is appreciated, thanks!

[image: User chosen interests]

Attached is my truncated code for a particular theme of interests, all the themes have the same code just different list.

Let's say my data has a list of [ " Home-body",  "‍♀️ Running", "‍♀️ Yoga",  " Theaters",  " Anime & Manga",].

What can be done so that the bubble UI of this chosen list is shown as bool isChosen (so yellow color, compared to the other dark ones)? Following which users can select and unselect again?

```
final List<String> artsInterests = [
  blah blah blah
];


class ArtsInterests extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArtsInterests({
    Key key,
    @required this.artsInterests,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> artsInterests;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final height = MediaQuery.size.height;
final width = MediaQuery.size.width;

    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: width * 0.045,
            top: height * 0.033),
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              ' Arts',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 21),
            )),
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: width * 0.03,
                top: height * 0.012),
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              height: height * 0.045,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  itemCount: 7,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return Interests2(AvailableInterestChosen(
                      artsInterests[index],
                      isChosen: false,
                    ));
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: width * 0.03,
                top: height * 0.003),
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              height: height * 0.045,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  itemCount: artsInterests.length - 7,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    return Interests2(AvailableInterestChosen(
                      artsInterests[7 + index],
                      isChosen: false,
                    ));
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

List<String> chosenInterests = [ " Home-body",  "‍♀️ Running", "‍♀️ Yoga",  " Theaters",  " Anime & Manga",];

List<String> chosenArtsInterests = [];

class Interests2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final AvailableInterestChosen viewInterest;

  Interests2(this.viewInterest);

  String id = 'Interests2';

  @override
  Interests2State createState() => Interests2State();
}

class Interests2State extends State<Interests2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final height = MediaQuery.size.height;
final width = MediaQuery.size.width;
    Container container = Container(
        height: height * 0.03,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: width * 0.027,
            vertical:height * 0.003),
        // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 6, 12, 6),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          width * 0.012,
          height * 0.003,
          width * 0.012,
          height * 0.003),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.viewInterest.isChosen && chosenInterests.length < 9
              ? Color(0xff0B84FE)
              : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.87),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.69),
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: 3,
              offset: Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
        ),
        child: Text(
          '${widget.viewInterest.title}',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: widget.viewInterest.isChosen && chosenInterests.length < 9
                  ? Colors.white
                  : Colors.black),
        ));

    if (widget.viewInterest.isChosen && chosenInterests.length < 9) {
      chosenArtsInterests.add('${widget.viewInterest.title}');
      var chosenInterests = chosenSportsInterests +
          chosenEntertainmentInterests +
          chosenCharacterInterests +
          chosenArtsInterests +
          chosenWellnessInterests +
          chosenLanguageInterests;

      print(chosenInterests);
    } else {
      chosenArtsInterests.remove('${widget.viewInterest.title}');
      var chosenInterests = chosenSportsInterests +
          chosenEntertainmentInterests +
          chosenCharacterInterests +
          chosenArtsInterests +
          chosenWellnessInterests +
          chosenLanguageInterests;

      print(chosenInterests);
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.viewInterest.isChosen = !widget.viewInterest.isChosen;
        });
      },
      child: container,
    );
  }
}

class AvailableInterestChosen {
  bool isChosen;
  String title;

  AvailableInterestChosen(this.title, {this.isChosen = false});
}
```

Comment: You are saying you have another interests page where the same ui should be rendered ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy yes Nisanth. the first page was the onboarding page, but as the user enters into the app, they have the option to update their interests. How do I reflect the interests selected on the onboarding page to the page where they can update their interests?
Keeping in mind that the onboarding page returns a blank state, where all the interests aren't selected. But the page within the app returns a different UI for the interests that are alrdy selected previously (selected interests in blue as seen in screenshot).

Comment: Another way to look at it, it's like building the same list as the onboarding page but having the list eg [ " Home-body", "‍♀️ Running", "‍♀️ Yoga", " Theaters", " Anime & Manga",] already selected instead of all interests unselected.

Comment: You can just reuse the same widget you are using here, but in your interests page, you can add functionality to first fetch them from the firebase and then set them in state

Comment: @NisanthReddy understood. What if I just want to try populating the page with a list of [ " Home-body", "‍♀️ Running", "‍♀️ Yoga", " Theaters", " Anime & Manga",], not firebase for now hahaha. Do you have any examples or any similar references of how I can put the code in setState? I've been finding it to no avail

Comment: in my mind, I have a feeling it's smth like for every string in the data, make the bool true and then add it to the list of ternary operator that changes UI color.

So it's like ``` for(var i in chosenInterests)  setState(() {
          widget.viewInterest.isChosen;
        });
```

But the exact place to put this and the exact code still needs to be found><

Comment: Yes exactly. That is correct and you will place this code wherever you want to show your list of interests. One other way is to have a central data manager that talks with firestore and in your interests screen, you could add a listener on that data manager, which will give your the list of selected interests, there you will again create a map of <interest, bool> like you said in that widget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232898/discussion-between-vegetasaiyan-and-nisanth-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values to another widget as arguments but that is not possible in this case since there are so many values. You have to use a state management solution. For starter you can use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: I have solved it, thanks! by any chance, do you know how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757987/how-to-make-scrolling-page-continue-even-when-tabbarview-reaches-the-top-flutte