# Change Colors of Selected Containers and Unselect? [Flutter]

Tags: list, flutter, boolean, containers, conditional-operator

They are containers filled with reasons to report a user.
How to change the code so that each individual container will change color upon tab on/off?
And also limit the selected reasons to 3 while printing the reasons to the chosenReportReasons list?

Attached is the truncated code:

```
final List<String> reportReasons = [
  'blah',
'blah blah',
'blah blah blah'
];

List<String> chosenReasonsToReport = [];
bool isSelected = false;

  Container(
                child: Wrap(
                    children: reportReasons
                        .map((reportReason) => GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                if (isSelected = false) {
                                  isSelected = true;
                                } else {
                                  isSelected = false;
                                }
                                setState(() {});
if (reportReason.isSelected && chosenReasonsToReport.length < 3) {
      chosenReasonsToReport.add('${reportReason}');

      print(chosenReasonsToReport);
    } else {
      chosenReasonsToReport.remove('${reportReason}');
     
      print(chosenReasonsToReport);
    }
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.021,
                                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                      0.009,
                                ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: isSelected
                                        ? Color(0xff4aa3f8)
                                        : Color(0xff3a327f),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        color:
                                            Colors.grey[50].withOpacity(0.60))),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                            0.027,
                                    vertical:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                            0.0045),
                                child: Text(
                                  reportReason,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 13.5,
                                      color: isSelected
                                          ? Color(0xff231b6a)
                                          : null),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList()),
```

Updated error of code

[image: Updated error of code]

Further Updated:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ReportPage(),
    );
  }
}


class RemarksModel {
  bool isSelected;
  String reason;

  RemarksModel({this.isSelected, this.reason});
}

class ReportPage extends StatefulWidget {

  List<RemarksModel> reportReasons;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    reportReasons = [
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'Sexually Harassing'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'Racially Discriminative'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'Shouting'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'Prank Calling'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'Scam Bots'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'Vulgarities Abusing'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'No Sound')
    ];
  }

  @override
  _ReportPageState createState() => _ReportPageState();
}

class _ReportPageState extends State<ReportPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
...
```

Comment: instead of making isSelected bool variable,  make it as index of selected. then check for the index of selected in reasons list.

Comment: Hi Nidheesh, thank you, this makes sense. By any chance, do you have an example of how I can do that ?

Comment: You will have to use initstate in _ReportPageState class

Comment: Thank you Nidheesh, can I have your linkedIn please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ease create a Model class for Reasons

```
class RemarksModel {
  bool isSelected;
  String reason;

  RemarksModel({this.isSelected, this.reason});
}
```

and can be initialized as

```
  List<RemarksModel> reportReasons;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    reportReasons = [
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'blah'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'blah blah'),
      RemarksModel(isSelected: false, reason: 'blah blah blah')
    ];
  }
```

then you can easily know whether the item is selected or not, and you can make an item select and deselect on the tap callback

```
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    reportReason.isSelected = !reportReason.isSelected;
                  });
                },
```

Full code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Wrap(
          children: reportReasons
              .map((reportReason) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        reportReason.isSelected = !reportReason.isSelected;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.021,
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.009,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: reportReason.isSelected
                              ? Color(0xff4aa3f8)
                              : Color(0xff3a327f),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.grey[50].withOpacity(0.60))),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.027,
                          vertical:
                              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0045),
                      child: Text(
                        reportReason.reason,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.5,
                            color: reportReason.isSelected
                                ? Color(0xff231b6a)
                                : null),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList()),
    );
  }
```

if you need a list of selected reasons only,

```
  List<RemarksModel> getSelectedReasons() {
    return reportReasons.where((reason) => reason.isSelected).toList();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Nidheesh once again. think we're getting there. When i put the initstate in the extends stateful widget. It says that the initstate isn't defined in a superclass of that state. 
I think this might be a super simple error regarding placement, learning as I go along.

Comment: please check spelling of `initState`

Comment: Yes Nidheesh, I have checked. I've updated the code and depicted the screenshot. Have a look.

Comment: try invalidating cache. it is working in the dart pad.

Comment: Have a look Nidheesh, i updated to show the initial part of the code. Might be placement issues.

Comment: Does the answer helped?

Comment: sure did bro, thanks for your help always!

Comment: by any chance, you know how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629779/reflect-list-data-back-into-ui-flutter

Answer (score 0):

try wrap these lines inside a **setState**:

```
if (isSelected = false) {
                                  isSelected = true;
                                } else {
                                  isSelected = false;
                                }
```

and remove the **setState** below.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but this doesn't change the state of the container too.